# Prove that all nxn nilpotent matrices of order n are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

I have to show that all $n \times n$ nilpotent matrices of order n are similar. My initial approach was to show that for all nilpotent matrices their minimun characteristic polynomial is of the form: $$\lambda^n$$

Is this sufficient?

Can someone show me a formal approach to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't prove it, because it isn't true. Consider $A=J_2(0)\oplus J_2(0)$ and $B=J_2(0)\oplus0_{2\times2}$ for instance. We have $A,B\ne0=A^2=B^2$, but $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Comment: Ouch, few seconds difference.. I didn't see your comment when I was writing my answer.

Comment: I have it as a homework assignment, I don't understand why our teacher did this...

Comment: I have edited the question. Is this statement true?

Comment: Okay, after your edit, the statement is true. This makes the current form of  my answer invalid. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Sorry about that, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Examples of nilpotent matrices of the same order that are not similar**

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & & & \\
& 0 & & \\
& & 0 & 1 \\
& & & 0 
\end{pmatrix}, \ \ B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1& & \\
& 0 & & \\
& & 0 & 1 \\
& & & 0  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
They both have
$$
A\neq 0, \ B\neq 0 , \ A^2 = B^2 = 0.
$$
However, these matrices $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

**Proof that the nilpotent $n\times n$ matrices of order $n$ are similar**

For nilpotent $n\times n$ matrix of order $n$, there is only one possible Jordan form. Since it is nilpotent, it has only $0$ as an eigenvalue. Since it is nilpotent of order $n$, it must be similar to the following Jordan block:
$$
J(0, n) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & & \cdots & \\
  & 0 & 1 & \cdots & \\
&\cdots & \\
& & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
& & \cdots & & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If the matrix has eigenvalue all zeros, and does not have Jordan form as above, the the nilpotency order is less than $n$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I didn't ask the question correctly. Is this true now?

Comment: Yes, it is true now.