# True/False Linear algebra questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve the following entrance exam problem.

Let $ \in _4(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $P^4$ is the zero matrix, but $P^3$ is a nonzero matrix.
Then which one of the following is FALSE?

(A) For every nonzero vector $ \in \mathbb{R}^4$, the subset $\{, P, P^2, P^3\}$ of the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ is linearly independent.

(B) The rank of $P^$ is $4 − $ for every $ \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

(C) $0$ is an eigenvalue of $P$.

(D) If $ \in _4(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $Q^4$ is the zero matrix, but $Q^3$ is a nonzero matrix, then there exists a nonsingular matrix $S \in _4(\mathbb{R}$ such that $^{−1} = $.

Note: $_ (\mathbb{R})$ = the real vector space of all $ \times $ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt**: After numerous trials and errors, I successfully constructed a matrix denoted $P$ given by  $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

However, I am currently facing a significant roadblock in solving this problem. I am struggling to comprehend the next steps to proceed forward.

Thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148117/discussion-on-question-by-srijan-true-false-linear-algebra-questions); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option $A$ Looks Obviously false... I can give a counter example $$T:\mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^4}: T(e_1)=0,T(e_2)=e_1,T(e_3)=e_2, T(e_4)=e_3$$ Where $\{e_i:1\leq i\leq 4 \}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$ .  Do you Know what is the matrix of T..? It is the same matrix given by you..

then we check A is false... $ $\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ $

Now take any one of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ let's take $e_1$. It is clear that $e_1 \neq 0$ then $$\{Te_1,T^2e_1,T^3e_1,T^4e_1\}=\{e_1,0,0,0\}$$ and hence it is obvious that it is not linearly independent.

For option D check [Prove that all nxn nilpotent matrices of order n are similar.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032029/prove-that-all-nxn-nilpotent-matrices-of-order-n-are-similar)

OR

[Proof that all $n\times n$ matrices that are nilpotent of order $n$ are similar.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339142/proof-that-all-n-times-n-matrices-that-are-nilpotent-of-order-n-are-similar?rq=1)

> CAUTION: option A is correct if it is given as `there exists` instead of `for all`

Comment: Dear Praveen.. Thank you so much for the answer. I understood fully.

Comment: @Srijan Glad to know that...